# How to create a generic extension function for an enum class annotated with kotlinx.serialization.Serializable?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, enums, kotlin-extension

Given the following Kotlin enum:

```kotlin
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
enum class MyEnum {
    @SerialName("One") ONE,
    @SerialName("Two") TWO,
    @SerialName("Three") THREE
}
```

I can call the following [generated function](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#plugin-generated-serializer):

```kotlin
MyEnum.serialize()
```

Sometimes I need to pipe this through an `kotlinx.serialization.builtins.ArraySerializer`:

```kotlin
ArraySerializer(MyEnum.serializer())
```

Which could be wrapped in an extension function:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> KSerializer<T>.asArray(): KSerializer<Array<T>> {
    return ArraySerializer(this)
}
```

as used like this:

```kotlin
MyEnum.serialize().asArray()
```

How can I write a **generic** extension function to do ...?

```kotlin
MyEnum.serializeAsArray()
```

Comment: generic in what sense? do you want it to be for every serializable object? or for any enum?

Comment: Generic for all enums which are annotated with `@Serializable`.